# How to change the Coordinate Reference System of a model to align with another?

Tags: workflow, import, coordinates, world

This is my first question on Stack Exchange :)

I just can't figure out how to align two models based on different Coordinate Reference Systems (CRS).

This is an imported DXF file based on Amersfoort / RD New -- Netherlands - Holland - EPSG:28992
[image]

Additionally I import an Openstreetmap model using the blender-OSM addon, I don't know which coordinate system it uses. But it is imported to another location.
[image]

I want them in the same place by assigning one model to the other coordinate system (preferably to RD New). The blendfile is attached. Maybe there is some smart mind out there that can help me with that? It would help me a lot!

Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the projection EPSG:28992 [addon docs](https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-osm/wiki/Documentation#custom-map-projections)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Yes I have. I pasted it in the SRID box but it still imports on another location. Is there something I have to check or change in the settings?

Comment: It works! turned out that the file wasn't reading the reference system. I now used BlenderGIS where you can add any reference as well. Than by using the projection addon it does import using the RD New system.